# Is there a word to describe "more demand than offer"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Is there a word which is used to describe the situation when demand for some goods are so high that sellers cannot satisfy it. It usually leads to rapid growth of prices and crowds in shops, even up to fights among buyers, 好像，抢购、轰涌对吗？In Russian, it is ажиотаж.

Comment: The situation is called `供不应求`, and the market for that situation is called `卖方市场`. "抢购" would be the **result** of that situation but not the situation itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think it is not appropriate. 通货膨胀 but not leads to crowd in shops.

Comment: 脱销would be the word you are looking for.

Comment: 脱销可以描述当很多人想要买什么商品的时候，供不应求，商店里人很多，很热闹。 脱销 can be used to In a crowed store Supplies fall short of demand? thanks.

Comment: iciba：脱销：out of stock ； sold out ， 
regarding ажиотаж see BKRS：1) 操纵股票价格 cāozòng gǔpiào jiàgé
2) перен. 热闹 rènǎo, 风潮 fēngcháo etc。

Comment: Agree with Stan that "供不應求" describes exactly what you said.

Answer (score 1):

供不應求 - literally 'supply/not/satisfied/demand'

僧多粥少 - idiom, not enough congee for the monks

Answer (score 0):

It should be "蜂拥”， rather than "轰涌”. And you can call the goods which is very popular "抢手货".